# removing files from git

Tags: git

I know I can remove a file from tracking and have it deleted with `git rm <file>`

or if I want to keep the file and just remove it from tracking I can use `git rm --cached <file>`

but what are the repercussions of this when I push it to the repository and other people pull from it? Makes sense that `git rm --cached <file>` would just remove it from tracking for everyone and they still have the file in their directory, but what about `git rm <file>`, will it just remove the file from tracking for other users or will it delete the actual file for them once they pull as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will delete that file for them, too. Actually that will happen in both cases - no matter if you use `--cached` or not since what you eventually commit will be the same thing: The deletion of the file.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is:

```
rm <file>
```

This will only removes the file from **the working tree**.

```
git rm <file>
```

This will removes file from **the working tree** and from **the index** (which is tracking by your words).

```
git rm --cached <file>
```

This will only remove file from **the index**.

If you remove file from the index, and push your commits, then the result is same, the file will be removed.